# Powershell Copy-Item Exit code 1

Tags: powershell, error-handling, exit-code, copy-item

I have a script with several files I'd like to copy and I do it more or less like so.

```
Copy-Item xxx1 yyy1 -Force
Copy-Item xxx2 yyy2 -Force
Copy-Item xxx3 yyy3 -Force
Copy-Item xxx4 yyy4 -Force
```

and so on.

Now I'd like this script to exit with 1 if any of the files was not copied.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for is similar to the `set -e` option in `bash`, which causes a script to exit instantly in the event that a command signals failure (except in conditionals)<sup>[1]</sup>.

PowerShell has no such option<sup>[2]</sup>, but you can emulate it:

```
# Set up a trap (handler for when terminating errors occur).
Trap { 
    # Print the error. 
    # IMPORTANT: -ErrorAction Continue must be used, because Write-Error
    #            itself would otherwise cause a terminating error too.
    Write-Error $_ -ErrorAction Continue
    exit 1 
}

# Make non-terminating errors terminating.
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

# Based on $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop', any error reported by
# Copy-Item will now cause a terminating error that triggers the Trap
# handler.
Copy-Item xxx1 yyy1 -Force
Copy-Item xxx2 yyy2 -Force
Copy-Item xxx3 yyy3 -Force
Copy-Item xxx4 yyy4 -Force

# Failure of an EXTERNAL PROGRAM must be handled EXPLICITLY,
# because `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` does NOT apply.
foo.exe -bar
if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) { Throw "foo failed." } # Trigger the trap.

# Signal success.
exit 0
```

**Note**:

- PowerShell-internally, exit codes are *not* used in error handling; they typically only come into play when invoking external programs from PowerShell, or when PowerShell / a PowerShell script needs to signal success vs. failure for the outside world (when called from another shell, such as `cmd` on Windows, or `bash` on Unix-like platforms).
- PowerShell's automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable reflects the exit code of the most recently executed external program / PowerShell script that called `exit <n>`.
- Calls to external (console/terminal) programs that signal failure via a nonzero exit code do *not* trigger the `trap` block, hence the explicit `throw` statement in the snippet above.
- Unless you set the exit code explicitly, it is the exit code of whatever external program happened to execute last that determines the script's overall exit code.

---

<sup>[1] Note that this option has its critics, because the exact rules around when a failure is tolerated and when it causes a script to abort are hard to remember - see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105</sup>

<sup>[2] Potentially adding support for it is being discussed in [this RFC proposal](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-RFC/pull/88).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, and it will exit with the number of powershell command errors.

```powershell
$errorcount = $error.count

Copy-Item xxx1 yyy1 -Force
Copy-Item xxx2 yyy2 -Force
Copy-Item xxx3 yyy3 -Force
Copy-Item xxx4 yyy4 -Force

exit $error.count - $errorcount
```