# powershell script stops if program fails (like bash `set -o errexit`)

Tags: bash, powershell

**Is there an elegant Powershell script setting that would exit the running Powershell script (or shell instance) if a program fails?**

I'm imagining something like Bash feature `set -o errexit` (or `set -e`) but for Powershell. In that feature, if a program in the bash script fails (process return code was not `0`) then the bash shell instance immediately exits.

In powershell, the script could expliclty check [`$LastExitCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?#lastexitcode) or `$?` (`if($?){exit}`). However, that becomes cumbersome to do for every program call. Maybe powershell has a feature to automatically check and react to program return codes?

### To explain in a script

Using made-up idiom `Set-Powershell-Auto-Exit`

```
Set-Powershell-Auto-Exit "ProgramReturnCode"  # what should this be?
& "program.exe" --fail  # this program fails with an error code
& "foo.exe"             # this never runs because script has exited
```

Comment: Can't you place the code in a Try Catch block and then simply exit?

Comment: @MarkKram a `try ... catch` would require many lines of code.  I was looking for a one-line statement that would set the powershell script mode, similar to bash `set -e`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, **as of PowerShell (Core) 7.3.x, PowerShell offers *no* way to automatically exit a script when an *external program* reports a nonzero exit code.**

- However, as first noted in [Daniel T's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76410068/45375), an **[*experimental* feature, `PSNativeCommandErrorActionPreference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/experimental-features)** is available in v7.3 and preview versions of v7.4, which, if the [`$PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#psnativecommandargumentpassing) is set to `$true`, emits a *PowerShell* error in response to an external program's nonzero exit code, which is therefore subject to the value of the [`$ErrorActionPreference` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#erroractionpreference); **caveat**:

  - [Experimental features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Experimental_Features) *may or may not* become stable features.
  - [This GitHub query](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+PSNativeCommandErrorActionPreference) shows a current list of unresolved issues relating to the experimental feature.

**For *PowerShell-native* commands *only*** (cmdlets, scripts, functions), **`$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`** can be used, which results in exit code `1`.

- If you need more control over what exit code is reported, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53248925/45375).
- For an overview of how PowerShell reports exit codes to the outside world, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57468523/45375).

**For *external programs***, you must **test for `$LASTEXITCODE -eq 0` *explicitly*** and take action based on that, but as a **workaround** you can **use a *helper function*** for all external-program invocations, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48877892/45375).

Answer (score 2):

As of PowerShell 7.3.0 preview, there is an experimental implementation for exiting scripts when external programs fail. The [new RFC PR has moved to another link](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-RFC/pull/277).

```
# Global config setup
Enable-ExperimentalFeature PSNativeCommandErrorActionPreference
exit
```

```
# Per-script setup
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$PSNativeCommandUseErrorActionPreference = $true

# Code from original question
& {
    & program.exe --fail  # this program fails with an error code
    & foo.exe             # this never runs because script has exited
}
```